# How is となりのトトロ supposed to be perceived in Japanese?

Tags: words, names

How is the title of the well-known cartoon となりのトトロ supposed to be perceived in Japanese?

What is the device behind the トトロ? Is it alliteration, word-play or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mei, the main character in the movie, has a tendency to mispronounce words.

**「トトロ」**is a mispronunciation of the word**「トロル」**or **「トロール」**, meaning  **"troll"**— which *may* refer to the antagonist of the classic children's story "The Three Billy Goats Gruff".

Sources:

[From Nausicaa](http://www.nausicaa.net/miyazaki/totoro/faq.html#what)

[From EN Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Neighbor_Totoro#cite_note-5)

Comment: でも、Wikiには「広報部が公式ブログでこれを否定する見解を発表」って書いてあるような気が・・・上のほうにも『「トトロ」の名前は「所沢のとなりのお化け」に由来している』って書いてあるし・・・